# Does the maven release plugin work for branches?

Tags: svn, maven, maven-3, maven-release-plugin

When I execute the maven release plugin from a branch that is in \branches\branchone
it creates a tag for \branches

I would like the plugin to tag just "branchone" but for some reason it tags the whole "branches" instead.

This seems like a bug, the plugin should use the current scm "connection" url to determine what to tag.

Do you know why the release plugin doesn't tag the correct directory?
or
Do you know any work-arounds?

Answer (score 3):

I use it prefectly to tag branches, you may have a problem in your scm config. Try something similar to:

```
<scm>
    <connection>scm:svn:http://svn.mydomain.com/repo/projectA/branches/projectA-3.1.x</connection>
    <developerConnection>scm:svn:http://svn.mydomain.com/repo/projectA/branches/projectA-3.1.x</developerConnection>
</scm>
```

Make sure that the pom on the branch have the exact same path as the branch is in the repo, otherwise you can have problems.

If you use de legacy layout (CVS-like layout), you may need to setup the tagBase (http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-release-plugin/prepare-mojo.html#tagBase).